# AJAX call not working, looking for the wrong action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want, on button press, an AJAX call to be sent to my `events_controller#check` action. This is the code I have:

**events\new.html.erb**:

```
<button id="check-button" type="button">Check</button>
```

**application.js:**

```
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){
    var checkList = []; //creates array to store customer ids
    ...
    });

    $.ajax({
            url: '/events/check',
            data:checkList
        }
    )

});
```

**events_controller#check**

```
def check
    checkList = params[:checkList]
    ...
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
post 'events_controller/check' => 'events#check'
```

I am getting this error in my console on button click:

```
Started GET "/events/check?undefined=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-03 11:36:33 +0000

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for EventsController):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'

...etc
```

Why is it trying to find the action 'show' and not 'check'? How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: you should write code of `checkList` set. Use `data:{"checkList":checkList.toString()}` here you are having `array` so make its csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems:

> 1. You've *probably* got `resources :events` before your declared route (why it's going to `show`)
> 2. You've not invoked the `POST` method

You should have the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :events do 
   post :check, on: :collection #-> url.com/events/check
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){
   var checkList = []; //creates array to store customer ids
   ...

   $.ajax({
     url: '/events/check',
     data: checkList,
     method: "POST"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, a post request is expected while type is missing in the request so it makes a `GET` request as a default request method.

You need to add `type` to your ajax:

```
type:'post',
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Check you have import Jquery file correctly in your page.

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   $.ajax({
      url: '/events/check', // Check URL is correct
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        //TO DO Action
      }
    });
```

2. Check url value you applied is correct. then use below code.